# How to resue setInterval function after clearing it? Only javascript please

Tags: javascript

Onmouseover(over an image) I am clearing the setInterval function. Onmouseout I need to reuse the same setInterval function. But since its cleared during mouseover event its not working on mouseout. How to make use of setinterval function once again onmouseout?

I am trying to create a slideshow widget(something like in YAHOO HOMEPAGE).

```
p = 0;

function list(event) {
    var x = event.target || event.srcElement;
    document.getElementById("outer").src = x.src;
    x.style.borderBottom = "thick solid #0000FF";
    allimg[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[g].style.borderBottom = "none";
    clearInterval(cha); //clearing autoincrement of images onmouseover
    clearInterval(rcli); //clearing autoright click button onmouseover
    clearInterval(chanid); //??? CLEARING HERE 
    x.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        x.style.borderBottom = "none";

        function chan() {
            allimg = document.getElementsByClassName("container"); //container within which all images are there
            u = allimg[0].getElementsByTagName('img');
            for (p; p < u.length; p++) {
                if (u[p].style.borderBottomStyle == "solid" || u[p] == x) {
                    a = p;
                    u[a].style.borderBottom = "none";
                    a++;
                    document.getElementById("outer").src = u[a].src;
                    u[a].style.borderBottom = "thick solid #0000FF";
                    break;
                }
            }
            p++;
        }
        chanid = setInterval(chan, 2000);

    });
}
```

Comment: could you paste the related code?

Comment: you can imagine what I am trying to create something like in yahoo Homepage. I can't able to paste all HTML code since everything lengthy. Here is the particular JS code and I am struck here

Answer (score 0):

Create the interval in a function, that way onmouseout you can just re-run this function.

Another way would be to leave the interval running but update a variable that stops the interval function from fully executing. Something like this:

```
var paused;

setInterval(onInterval, 1000);

$img.on("mouseover", function () {

    // on mouseover 'pause' the interval
    paused = true;
})
.on("mouseout", function () {

    // on mouseout 'unpause' it
    paused = false;
});

function onInterval () {

    // if paused do nothing
    if(paused) return;

    // do regular interval stuff here

}
```